# Can I edit the text of sign in button on Google?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-plus, google-signin

I am integrating my application with google plus. I have installed google play services and signed in to my account. Also I could publish and plus one for what ever I want.

#### My problem

I can't change the text of the sign in button.

#### My code

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/share_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Share on Google+" />
```

#### What I have tried?

- First, I tried adding this line to the xml

  ```
  android:text="Share on Google+"
  ```
- Secondly, I tried to set the text programmatically, however it didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

#### Edit

If it is not possible, is there any way so I can use the same google sign in button on another button?

Comment: It doesn't look like its possible.

Comment: @vikram is there any other way so i can use the same style of that button on another button ?

Comment: You can read through `Customizing your sign-in button` on this page: [Google+ Sign-in for Android](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in). `SignInButton` has some static values that may help you give a custom buttom a similar look. For example: [SignInButton.COLOR_LIGHT](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/SignInButton.html#COLOR_LIGHT). More here: [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/SignInButton.html).

Comment: @vikram from `customizing your sign in button` they didn't say any thing about customize the sign in button they just say that you can create a button and use google's string resource , thus in this case i could benefit from the sign in style,

Comment: So, you will need to create a regular button and style it to look like the `SignInButton`.

Comment: @vikram I am doing that, i am overwhelmed cos google didn't allow me to use its styles as facebook did

Comment: A simple solution could be creating your own  Google Sign In button simply using a TextView with the Google logo came with Google signing library this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78253033/7835969

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Here is the technique that I used:

```
protected void setGooglePlusButtonText(SignInButton signInButton, String buttonText) {
    // Find the TextView that is inside of the SignInButton and set its text
    for (int i = 0; i < signInButton.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = signInButton.getChildAt(i);

        if (v instanceof TextView) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) v;
            tv.setText(buttonText);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this isn't marked as the correct answer it definitely works. I'm surprised google doesn't have a method for setting this directly

Comment: As risky as well, if Google button change implementation and we aware of comming from google service and for that every update that this library involve.

Comment: is it possible to change google image height & width programatically ??

Comment: I also wrapped it as a binding adapter - so could use it in multiple places and setting text in xml

Comment: I get impressed by the narrow sight of most developers here, to suggest a person do this is bad, to accept it as an answer is worse, to even complain that this wasn't accept as answer only shows people haven't created any app that last longer than one year

Comment: @Xenione What risk do we have in using this approach ?

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy SignInButton is a third-party component, which means it is out of your control, if a new version of SignInButton is released and it is changed the internal hierarchical-view arrangement and there's no Textview that holds the text as SignInButton child your code is going to fail silently, and there is a huge problem, maybe take months to relise of that.

Comment: @Xenione thanks, understood. What can we do to overcome the problems in this approach ? Or is there any better way to achieve the same thing ?

Answer (score 36):

Here is the easiest way that I used:

```
    TextView textView = (TextView) signInButton.getChildAt(0);
    textView.setText("your_text_xyz");
```

Answer (score 20):

**Problem:**

Other answers have mentioned a workaround. The underlying implementation of the button may change any time which would cause the code to break. I felt uncomfortable trying to use the hacks. For a clean solution, you would think that setting `android:text` on the `com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton` in your layout file would do the trick. However it turns out that that attribute is not available for `SignInButton`.

**Aim**

[image]
[image]

**Google's guidelines**

From documentation, Google suggests creating a custom button as mentioned on [Customizing the Sign-In Button](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/custom-button) [Archived now. See the archived page [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150926063503/https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/custom-button)]. It suggests using the branding guidelines as mentioned at [Sign-In Branding Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines#sign-in-button). This includes using the given custom icons and images in the button, setting specific text size, paddings and other do's and don'ts for the logo.

**Clean Solution**:

Doing as per Google's suggestion involves some custom work. I was willing to do that but wanted to create something reusable, so that others won't have to go through this again. That's why I wrote a quick small (4KB) library does that. Feel free to contribute to it for everyone's benefit if you find issues.

- **Step 1:** Add the following to your `app` module level `build.gradle` file:

  ```
    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.github.shobhitpuri:custom-google-signin-button:2.0.0'
    }
  ```
- **Step 2:** Also, add the following in the top-level build.gradle file:

  ```
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
  ```
- **Step 3:** In your XML Layout, have the following:

  ```
    <RelativeLayout
        ...
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <com.shobhitpuri.custombuttons.GoogleSignInButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/google_sign_up"
            app:isDarkTheme="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
  ```

**Usage**

- **`android:text="{string}"`**: As usual to set the text on the button.
- **`app:isDarkTheme="{Boolean}"`**: To switch between blue theme and white theme for the button. The library handles changing of text color and background color. It also handles the change of color on button press or button clicks.

**Source**:

- GitHub: https://github.com/shobhitpuri/custom-google-signin-button
- Blog Post: http://go.shobhitpuri.com/googlesignin

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Link to "Customizing the Sign-In Button" is now 404

Comment: Thanks @Lefty for the comment. Can you please add more details or create an issue on the repository with the details to help debug it? https://github.com/shobhitpuri/custom-google-signin-button/issues Thanks so much :)

Comment: @ShobhitPuri Actually there's already an open issue on the same: https://github.com/shobhitpuri/custom-google-signin-button/issues/8
I tried it n it doesnt work, it changes the button to look like a typical android Button with the custom text, even the theme doesnt work.

Comment: @Lefty There is an updated `1.1.0` version of the library which supports AndroidX now. Please let me know if you come across other issues.

Answer (score 1):

`android:text` will not work because of Google's Sign in button is a `FrameLayout` but not a `Button`.

Since text property is only meant for Views representing textual format but not for ViewGroups, your solution is not working.

The only way you can achieve is getting the `TextView` defined inside `FrameLayout` as explained by **w.donahue**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this class I wrote based on the answer of `w.donahue` that you can find in this page:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;

public class GoogleLoginButton extends FrameLayout implements View.OnClickListener{

    private SignInButton signInButton;
    private OnClickListener onClickListener;

    public GoogleLoginButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public GoogleLoginButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public GoogleLoginButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        signInButton = new SignInButton(getContext());
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        setGooglePlusButtonText(signInButton, "Test");
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        addView(signInButton, params);
    }

    protected void setGooglePlusButtonText(SignInButton signInButton, String buttonText) {
        // Find the TextView that is inside of the SignInButton and set its text
        for (int i = 0; i < signInButton.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = signInButton.getChildAt(i);

            if (v instanceof TextView) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) v;
                tv.setText(buttonText);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
        if(this.signInButton != null) {
            this.signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(this.onClickListener != null && v == this.signInButton) {
            this.onClickListener.onClick(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I use this?

Answer (score 1):

**For Beginners**

Avoiding few crashes.

```
try {
            ((TextView) mGoogleSignOutBtn.getChildAt(0)).setText(R.string.sign_out);
} catch (ClassCastException | NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

***XML file***

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
         android:id="@+id/google_login_button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/new_googlebtn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                    android:text="@string/google_login"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    app:icon="@drawable/googleg_standard_color_18"
                    app:iconGravity="textStart"
                    app:iconPadding="10dp"
                    app:iconTint="#00100D0D"
                    app:iconTintMode="src_atop" />
```

***UNMODIFIED MAIN ACTIVITY FILE***

```
google_signInButton=findViewById(R.id.google_login_button);
        google_signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, SIGN_IN);

            }
        });
```

**UPDATED Main Activity file**

```
google_signInButton=findViewById(R.id.google_login_button);
        new_googlebtn=findViewById(R.id.new_googlebtn);
        new_googlebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (v== new_googlebtn) {
                    google_signInButton.performClick();
                }
                    Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, SIGN_IN);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

For kotlin you can do this.

```
val googleTextView: TextView = SignInButton.getChildAt(0) as TextView
    googleTextView.text = "Sign In with Google"
```

SignInButton is reference to the button id you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I encorage not to use those @w.donahue approach since it violates several principles as open/close principle. Best approach it's to customize your own sign in button. If you see documentation about Sign in Google plus button is just a FrameLayout with Textview. At this link https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines#sign-in-button you have material to design the button.

```
public class GplusButton extends FrameLayout {

private final String logIn="log in with google +";

private final String logOut="log out";

TextView labelTV;

public GplusButton(Context context) {
    super(context, null);
}

public GplusButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_g_plus_signin_normal);
    addTextLabel();
}

public void addTextLabel() {
    labelTV = new TextView(getContext());
    setTextLogIn();
    labelTV.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    addView(labelTV, params);
}

public void setTextLogIn(){
    labelTV.setText(logIn);
}

public void setTextLogOut(){
    labelTV.setText(logOut);

}
```

The only annoying thing is that even Google + mark with 9 patch extension the PNG they aren't, so you have to edit.

Comment: Should work to create a look-a-like button, but how do I trigger the sign-in event, I believe this method is not accessible to us programmers.

Comment: Sign in google button neither implement sign in. you must implemente it, so just add a onClicklistener through setOnclikClistener FrameLayout methode and create GoogleApiClient and start connection as show in doc

Answer (score 0):

Why not create your own simple Google SignIn button using a TextView and the Google logo came up with Google signing library:

```
<TextView
    android:text="Sign In with Google"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/<of your choice if required>"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/googleg_standard_color_18"/>
```

[image]