# Adding a google sign in button - sign in problems

Tags: android, google-plus

I am trying to put google sign in button in my android app.
I have take reference from https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in and it showing me continuous progress bar and doesn't log into my account.
I have already added my id on emulator.
I am attaching the image of it.
And here is my code.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "ExampleActivity";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR = 9000;

    private ProgressDialog mConnectionProgressDialog;
    private PlusClient mPlusClient;
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
                .setActions("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity", "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity")
                .build();
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        mConnectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mConnectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        // We've resolved any connection errors.
        mConnectionProgressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(this, " User is connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        Log.d(TAG, "disconnected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (mConnectionProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            // The user clicked the sign-in button already. Start to resolve
            // connection errors. Wait until onConnected() to dismiss the
            // connection dialog.
            if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
                try {
                    connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    mPlusClient.connect();
                }
            }
        }

        // Save the intent so that we can start an activity when the user clicks
        // the sign-in button.
        mConnectionResult = connectionResult;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button && !mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
            if (mConnectionResult == null) {
                mConnectionProgressDialog.show();
            } else {
                try {
                    mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    // Try connecting again.
                    mConnectionResult = null;
                    mPlusClient.connect();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mConnectionResult = null;
            mPlusClient.connect();
        }
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

androidmanifest.xml

```
![<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.GooglePlusDemo"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>


    <application
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity
                android:name="MyActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>]
```

[image]

Even after turn on google api in console it shows me error 
and google+ app is already installed on my device.
i am posting both images.

[image]

[image]

Comment: update play serwices of imulator to 3.1

Comment: and atlest once plz try to texst on real devices its works fine its not an issue

Comment: how to update in emulator? i dont have real device with me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536595/how-to-download-google-play-services-in-a-android-emulator

Comment: @DigveshPatel i check on real device but same issue.

Comment: is google plus install on device??

Comment: yeah it is already installed on my device

Comment: actually there are not an single line wrong in code but i think its another problem behind code like setting or turn on Google plus api in google api console

Comment: yeah i forgot to on :P

Comment: hey even after turn on google plus api it shows me progrssbar only

Comment: have you generate project on console with same package name?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46814/discussion-between-riddhi-shah-and-digvesh-patel)

Comment: just remove emai address fromimages of console

Comment: just remove emai address from images u uploaded

Comment: your email directly display to all user so i have advices you to remove that image or make black portion over it

Comment: hey ri8 also seen in right corner above image above yellow mesage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mPlusClient.connect();` is not being called anywhere. 
 you are just showing the progress bar in the click event rather than trying to connect.

[link](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started)

From Plusclient doc

You should instantiate this object in your Activity's onCreate(Bundle) method and then call connect() in onStart() and disconnect() in onStop(), regardless of the state.

Try adding mPlusClient in onStart or in the button click.

Comment: hey its done. i was testing in emulator. and when i run on real device it works perfectly. but how can i show the user's id on sign in button like text abc@gmail.com

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040815/can-i-edit-the-text-of-sign-in-button-on-google) no straightforward methods i guess.

Comment: not working , was already trying and yeah no straight forward method . thanks for help