# Customize Google SignInButton In Android

Tags: java, android, xml, google-plus, google-signin

I want to customise Google SignIn Button In Android. Currently I have a very basic default layout by using following code.

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I am not satisfied with the current button layout. Is it possible to update the button text, background colour in the default button, Or Should I create full custom button layout?

Thank you.

ps: I am new to Android

Comment: You can create your desired custom button and set a click-listener on it to perform click event on SignInButton using mSignInButton.performClick(). For more info, refer to this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick())

Comment: it dosen't wokr for google btn, but for facebook it dose. Any idea for google?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040815/can-i-edit-the-text-of-sign-in-button-on-google/46213682#46213682 answer can be useful in customizing the button text and theme easily and the recommended way by Google.

Answer (score 3):

Its very simple , you need to do this

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/button"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:text="@string/common_signin_button_text_long" />
```

You can customize your button , but you will have to make sure you follow the [guidelines](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines#sign-in-button).
Edit: Check out this library [custom signin button](https://github.com/championswimmer/Android-SocialButtons)

If you want to do it yourself you can create a linear layout and add images.

Comment: Any idea how I can add google icon on the left of the button?  I struggled a lot. Thanks

Comment: I updated the answer , if you find my answer helpful please accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to do it pragmatically rather than xml something like this

```
public static void customizeGooglePlusButton(SignInButton signInButton) {
    for (int i = 0; i < signInButton.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        View v = signInButton.getChildAt(i);

        if (v instanceof TextView)
        {
            TextView tv = (TextView) v;
            tv.setText("My Text");
            tv.setAllCaps(true);
            tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.smiley, 0, 0, 0);
            //here you can customize what you want  
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

another way but not that secure

```
TextView textView = (TextView) signInButton.getChildAt(0);
//Customize here
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, Google SignInButton is a FrameLayout you can customize it 
as you want but need some dynamic tweaks.

**XML part** 
   adding custom background to the frame layout, make your own.

```
  <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
                    android:id="@+id/google_signIn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/google_bottun_bg"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

                // google image logo
                <ImageView android:layout_width="16dp"
                           android:layout_height="16dp"
                           android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                           android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                           app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_gmail"/>
  </com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton>
```

2. inside FrameLayout we have a textView so you can redesign text view as needed

   ```
     fun reDesignGoogleButton(signInButton: SignInButton, buttonText: String) {
            for (i in 0 until signInButton.childCount) {
             val v = signInButton.getChildAt(i)
             if (v is TextView) {
              v.text = buttonText //setup your text here
              v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent) //setting transparent color that will hide google image and white background
              v.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white)) // text color here
              v.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD // even typeface 
              return
                }
             }
          }
   ```

   **Happy Coding**

[**see the results**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tDUg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

No need any library. The nice trick is to create your fully `custom layout`  then place `google btn` in this layout and set `width` and `height` match parent for `Google Sign in Button`, then set Visibility for Google Btn = 0 and then in

```
googleSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                googleLayoutCustom.setPressed(true);
                Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
        });
```

So Google Sign In btn will be on top of all layouts and your custom layout will perform touch ripple on google btn click.

P.S sure you have to implement touch ripple effect with any colors you want in your drawable. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/colorMain">

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

</ripple>
```