# Google Sign in button custom design android

Tags: android, google-signin

i'm designing a layout, where i need a user to signup using google sign button. But i want to ask that, is it possible to give custom design to google sign in button?
Because the layout is not looking attractive and i want to make it look attractive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Customize Google SignInButton In Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43999960/customize-google-signinbutton-in-android)

Comment: i'm little bit confused, because google forbade to give custom design to google sign in button. The thing i'm asking that, is it possible that i use image view or button instead of google sign in button give it custom design and google sign in intent as i desire?

Answer (score 2):

Yes sure you can use your  `Button` or `Image` for the Google Sign button instead of the one given in `xml`. First you need to use the icons given by the Google following the Guidelines and not custom made [check here for guidelines](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines) and [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/images/signin-assets.zip) to download them.

Let us say you define an `ImageView` as

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="40dp"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/signgoogle"
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_google"
            />
```

Then you can go to Java and get the Image by ID

```
googlesignin = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_google);
```

Attach an `OnClickListener` to it

```
googlesignin.setOnClickListener(v -> signInGoogle());
```

Then do the required signing in process

```
private void signInGoogle() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();

        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
```

Let me know if this solved your query. Also be sure to use the icons as given by them because they have rights over use of Signing up using their name. You can do some changes with the original icon as well as given [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines)

Comment: But as stated in the google sign in branding guidelines,(https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines). You can only use styles as light or dark. Giving custom design to google sign in button is prohibited. isn't it?

Comment: Ahh yes thank you for it, I forgot to add about this. Let me Edit the answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'll check it out.