# Localize google sign in button at runtime

Tags: android, google-signin

I am developing an android app which has a setting option to change the language. It works fine, but the google sign in button doesn't change the language until I close the app and reopen it.

This is the code of the onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    String language = "en";
    if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("es")) {
        language = "es";
    }

    String languagePref = prefs.getString(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.settings_language_key), language);

    Locale locale = new Locale(languagePref);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    setContentView(start_view);

    SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

    // Set the dimensions of the sign-in button.
    if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
    } else {
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    }
```

And this is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".StartActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    style="@style/StartViewDrawerContainer">

    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/StartViewParentVertical">

        <!-- Some GUI elements -->

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/StartViewMainContainer">

            <!-- More GUI elements -->

            <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
                android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
                style="@style/StartViewSignInButton"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        style="@style/StartViewNavigationView"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This code works great for every string literal but not for the google button.

Is there any way to localize the sign in text programmatically?

Comment: google sign button its not simple button. u can use after adding google gsm library if u want to change language of google sign button than add XML simple button and design like google button than u can change language of google sign in button

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean when you say adding google gsm library. Can you give me more details? Thank you!

Comment: i think u want google authentication in your app? than u want use this library in your gradle.  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'

Comment: Yes, I am using google authentication with no problem. My issue is about the language of the text shown in the sign in button. It does not change dinamically when the language of the app changes

Comment: put your xml file or google sign in button code

Comment: Done, I've added the layout with the button

Comment: if u any query check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040815/can-i-edit-the-text-of-sign-in-button-on-google                 same problem like u

Comment: I've checked it before posting my question, but I don't like that solution because it only changes the button text, not the dialog displayed to chose the account. I'm looking for a solution which allows me to localize the entire process of sign in. Thank you anyway!

Comment: simple u want to use simple XML button than your problem was solved

Comment: Nop, it doesn't work if I change the language of the application at runtime, it shows the literals of the initial language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've solved the issue defining the literals for every language and setting it programmatically with the instructions

```
TextView signInText = (TextView) signInButton.getChildAt(0);
signInText.setText(getString(R.string.sign_in));
```

Comment: You can trigger a UI refresh programmatically when the local changes. Android broadcasts an intent that you can capture in your application. See `ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED`

Answer (score 2):

**Issue with workarounds:**

By using workaround like `signInButton.getChildAt(0);`, the issue is that the underlying implementation of the button may change any time which would cause the code to break.

**Clean solution:**

For a clean solution, Google suggests [creating a custom button](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/custom-button). To prevent from re-doing the work every time, I've create a reusable custom button as a light 4KB library, where you can choose to have `android:text` on the Button itself. This will pickup the correct localization from `string.xml` file based on the language set.

- **Step 1:** Add the following to your `app` module level `build.gradle` file:

  ```
    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.github.shobhitpuri:custom-google-signin-button:2.0.0'
    }
  ```
- **Step 2:** Also, add the following in the top-level build.gradle file:

  ```
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
  ```
- **Step 3:** In your XML Layout, have the following:

  ```
    <RelativeLayout
        ...
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <com.shobhitpuri.custombuttons.GoogleSignInButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/google_sign_up"
            app:isDarkTheme="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
  ```

**Usage**

- `android:text="{string}"`: As usual to set the text on the button.
- `app:isDarkTheme="{Boolean}"`: To switch between blue theme and white theme for the button. The library handles changing of text color and background color. It also handles the change of color on button press or button clicks.

**Source**:

- GitHub: https://github.com/shobhitpuri/custom-google-signin-button
- Blog Post: http://go.shobhitpuri.com/googlesignin
- More on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46213682/1306419

Hope it helps.